# Partial update in django rest view

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have view for working with users profile. Which implement put and delete methods. How can i add patch method or use method for updating only one field(create/update avatar field)?

views.py:

```
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.generics import RetrieveAPIView
from rest_framework.mixins import UpdateModelMixin, DestroyModelMixin
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser, FormParser
from rest_framework.serializers import ValidationError

from djangorestframework_camel_case.parser import CamelCaseJSONParser

from api.models import User
from api.permissions import IsOwnerOrReadOnly
from api.auth.serializers import username_validation
from .serializers import AccountSerializer


class AccountAPIView(RetrieveAPIView, UpdateModelMixin, DestroyModelMixin):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsOwnerOrReadOnly, permissions.IsAuthenticated)
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser, CamelCaseJSONParser)


    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.request.user
        new_username = self.request.data.get('username', None)
        if new_username and user.username != new_username:
            try:
                username_validation(new_username)
            except ValidationError as error:
                Response(str(error), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from api.models import User, Album, Photo, Like

class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'avatar', 'bio', 'location')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
partial=True
```

in serializer enble  partial edits

Answer (score 0):

Simpliest solution it is just use the same principal as in put and delete methods:

```
def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.usernameCheck()
        return self.partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```